# Inflate de-compression: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a listener in Java that will listen on System.in, read data that has been compressed using Deflate, de-compress the data and then write it out to System.out.

I want to process the data that is streamed to System.in in real time so I need to keep the socket connection and input stream open while decompressing the data. It is also important that the de-compressed data is read out line by line. I have implemented the following code to read from the compressed stream and write to a new output stream:

```
    InputStream inputStream = System.in;
    InflaterInputStream inflaterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(inputStream);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inflaterInputStream));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

I am testing the code with the following Linux command:

```
    cat file_with_compressed_data.txt | java Inflate > outputFile.txt
```

Where Inflate is my System.in listener class. However, when running this command I receive the following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:223)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        at Inflate.main(Inflate.java:30)
```

The decompression seems to be working as outputFile.txt contains most of the original de-compressed data. However, there are some lines missing from outputFile.txt that are in the original file.

I can't see why this exception is getting thrown. Is there any other way I can de-compress Deflated data in real time without closing my input stream?

My java version is:

```
    java version "1.6.0_33"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)
```

Compressed files can be created using:

```
    DeflaterOutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(System.out);
    int c;
    while ((c = System.in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(c);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: Maybe your input file uses a different character encoding than the default that is used by `InputStreamReader`? Try specifying encoding explicitly.

Comment: Can you give a (preferably short) example of a way to generate a `file_with_compressed_data.txt` that will trigger this error?

Comment: @DanGetz Added code to create compressed files to the main question.

Comment: Thanks. When I test your code I don't get any error at all. However, something seems different to me between your code and your (intended) question: you mention "not closing the input stream", but your code examples all involve streams that get closed.

Comment: @DanGetz Yes I think the root of the problem is that some of the files I'm piping in are not formatted correctly. However, in the live environment the files are produced by another processing system so I don't have control over their production.

I need it to handle malformed files as well. Weirdly, if I de-compress by reading the compressed input stream into a `InflaterOutputStream` the malformed files de-compress correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I have found a solution to the problem. I looks as though it was the BufferedReader that was causing the issues, although I must admit I still don't understand why. I have replaced the BufferedReader with a StringBuilder to produce:

```
InputStream inputStream = System.in;
InflaterInputStream inflaterInputStream =  new InflaterInputStream(inputStream);

StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();
int c;
while ((c = inflaterInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    toReturn.append((char) c);
    if ((char) c == '\n') {
        System.out.println(toReturn.toString());
        toReturn.setLength(0);
    }
}
```